# Custom Cursor query to get data from content://sms/sent

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-query

I find this function in web android developer offficial

`public final Cursor query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)`

Now, I want to get sms from content://sms/sent , with thread_id of sms I will get only sms newest.

I will explain by example:

```
id   | thread_id |        phone     |       body

10       47
9        46 
8        47
7        45 
6        47 
5        43
4        45
3        42
2        41
1        47
```

For result I want to receive is:

```
 id   | thread_id |        phone     |       body

10       47
9        46     
7        45 
5        43
3        42
2        41
```

How must I do with query above?
Thanks.

Comment: read about `max` and `group by` in sql(ite)

Comment: @pskink but seem function Cursor query above not use for Uri ? And you can give me a small example is very useful for because I also search more but can succes, and thanks for your comment.

Comment: ah sorry, its taken from `ContentResolver#query`... so no, you cannot use `group by`, you have to iterate over the `Cursor` and find the max `id` in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You must use `GROUP BY thread_id` , see more details in my github repository [SmsMessenger](https://github.com/alishari/SmsMessenger), you can get it by following query:

```
    Cursor cursor = MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms")
            , null
            , "address IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (thread_id"
            , null
            , null);
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { // must check the result to prevent exception
        do {
   String messageText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
   System.out.println("messageText : "+messageText );
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```